# Increment date by day and input in new string

Tags: python, string, loops, date

Unsure of how to approach incrementing dates by day and inserting the new date into an existing string.

ie: `"...dates": '2017-01-01'...`

incremented to 
`..."dates": '2017-01-02'...`
and input into an existing string in the `"dates"` field in elasticsearch

Please help, I haven't been able to find anything like this in Python, only in Java.

Comment: String don't have "fields" in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [23]: import datetime as dt                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

In [24]: day1 = dt.datetime.strptime("2017-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

In [25]: for i in range(10): 
    ...:     day = day1 + dt.timedelta(days=i) 
    ...:     print("dates:", day.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
dates: 2017-01-01
dates: 2017-01-02
dates: 2017-01-03
dates: 2017-01-04
dates: 2017-01-05
dates: 2017-01-06
dates: 2017-01-07
dates: 2017-01-08
dates: 2017-01-09
dates: 2017-01-10
```

Comment: is there a way to access every line of dates to be printed out? becasue when i do x = day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') and then print x only the last date is outputted, not all of them

Comment: @aesthetics: I have a feeling you're doing that outside of the loop. Stick the `x = ...` in the for-loop and you should be fine... or append everything to a list